# WSO2 Identity Server X509Certificate Authenticator

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.

We need to provide authentication for the user or by using credentials (username/password) or by presenting a X509Certificate generated by a trusted CA.

The situation is that it can happen that the user presenting the X509Certificate will not be present in any of the user stores configured in WSO2.

What I'd like to obtain is a kind of "external" IdP behaviour. What I mean is that when the user clicks on "*Sign In With x509 Certificate*" WSO2 IS will only checks if the X509Certificate is valid and if it's valid it allows the user's authentication

If this feasible by using the X509Authenticator module?

Comment: Actually to authenticate users from X509 certificate, that user must be in a userstore of WSO2 Identity Server because when creating the certificate we need the username of the user which is registered in WSO2 IS. You can find an example from the following link. https://medium.com/@piraveenaparalogarajah/configuring-x509-certificate-authenticator-in-wso2-identity-server-9b6e30428e78

Comment: Yes I saw it... what I did is to modify the source code. I put a configuration parameter (I love the toml solution) and if true I’ll skip the check inside the wso2 repository I just check the certificate